# post_name is not stored until post is published... where should I store my slug until it goes live then?

Tags: posts, permalinks, post-meta, slug

**important** try as normal contributor user, not as admin

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214501/wp-no-slug-when-adding-a-pending-post) I actually have it reproduced. Seems like a bug to me but whatever. I want users to choose their slug. Well, as you cannot store post_name in pending posts, where should I store it? where does wordpress store the slug the user chooses while it is still draft / pending?

**EDIT**

my code, this works as it is publish status:

```
  $post_information = array(
    'post_title' => 'Your title',
  'post_content' => 'blabla',
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_author' => wp_get_current_user()->ID,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_name' => "somerandomstuffthatisunique222"
);
$new_id = wp_insert_post( $post_information);

$postl = get_post($new_id);
```

this does not work

```
       $post_information = array(
    'post_title' => 'Your title',
  'post_content' => 'blabla',
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_author' => wp_get_current_user()->ID,
  'post_status' => 'pending',
  'post_name' => "somerandomstuffthatisunique2223434343434"
);
$new_id = wp_insert_post( $post_information);
```

in case 2, post_name is empty string after insert.

the author doesn't matter

Comment: please post your code. anyway that code does not set an author which might or might not be the issue.there

Answer (score 0):

When you use the graphical interface, `post_name` is stored in the `wp_posts` table even for draft posts as soon as you modify the default value.

I tried your code (case 2) and I actually see the new entry in the database, with the correct `post_name`. Perhaps your check to post_name is not correct ?

Comment: try it as not admin user, I will update the question. As super admin, it worked for me too, but not as , say, contributor with simple 'edit_posts' privileges

Comment: well you beat me to it, I think it was the missing `publish_posts` or `edit_published_posts` rule that you can set in the User Role Editor using the "User Role Editor" plugin

Comment: OK, so that was a user capabilities issue ? Is it solved now ?